# ANDROID: What is the main idea behind of using strings.xml?

Tags: android

Someone please explain what is the main idea of using **strings.xml**?
I think it would be useful for multi-language support but how can we organise it for that?
Do I need it if I don't want to use multi-language support in my android application?

Comment: May be you don't want to convert your application to other languages. But Stander is stander

Comment: If we use a certain string in more than one place, do we really need to change it in every place if its value changes? Use strings.xml

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The idea is that it represents a single location for various strings, so your code isn't peppered with string literals.  In addition to that, you gain the ability to easily localize.  Organization of files for localization is covered here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html#creating-alternatives

Do you need it if you're not localizing?  No.  But it may make things easier in the long run, and I would recommend using it just for that reason.

Comment: I've been using strings.xml to store Strings but not for localization purposes. I've been using it because it's easier to override these Strings when using Android Library Projects. My question is **how safe is it** to store important strings like md5 keys in strings.xml? I have md5 keys that change depending on the Application Project, but the code that uses it is in the Library Project, so I store the String in strings.xml and override the file in each Application Project.

Answer (score 5):

Hard-coding strings is Bad.

Parameterizing strings (e.g. with strings.xml) is Good.

Being able to *internationalize* your strings (with language and/or locale-specific versions of strings.xml) is even Better :)

PS:

To make use of internationalization, just create resource subdirectories.  Google will give you plenty of references/examples.  Herre's one:

> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

```
* res/values/strings.xml   
  Contains English text for all the strings that the application
  uses, including text for a string named title.

* res/values-fr/strings.xml 
  Contain French text for all the strings, including title.

* res/values-ja/strings.xml
  Contain Japanese text for all the strings...
```

And yes, you should absolutely get in the habit of using strings.xml (and colors.xml and dimens.xml etc etc) even if you don't plan on internationalizing immediately.

IMHO....

Comment: I've been using strings.xml to store Strings but not for localization purposes. I've been using it because it's easier to override these Strings when using Android Library Projects. My question is **how safe is it** to store important strings like md5 keys in strings.xml? I have md5 keys that change depending on the Application Project, but the code that uses it is in the Library Project, so I store the String in strings.xml and override the file in each Application Project.