# How to set the language as French of my android application?

Tags: android

I have to change my application's language to French programmatically, so all texts a should be displayed in french.My app has set of activities and one background service so activity can registered with service and send and receive information from the server. Server will send data in French language so i need to display the same as well as if user wants to update any text on edit text then it should popup the Querty key pad with french characters support.

Please help me to resolve it.

Regards,
Piks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Localization**

in that create different values folders for  different locale objects.each values folder contains its own strings.xml files ( for strings ),colors.xml files ( for colors ).
   pick appropriate resource when the localization is changed (using enumalator settings Home -->Menu --> Settings -->
    Language & Keyboard --> Select language)

Comment: for more details go through the below link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102613/android-what-is-the-main-idea-behind-of-using-strings-xml

Comment: Thanks Rajeswari its true, we are also doing the same creating values-fr folder and added strings.xml file, but here scenario is bit different, Application will be running on the device and keep it communicating with the server and server will send the french strings so user should not bother about to change the language setting in the device means without changing the language setting on the device ,app should display text in the french and when user tap on the edit text, it should popup querty keypad with all french characters supported.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Localization](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/localization/index.html). This might help you.