# Why we don't directly assign values for layout views in android?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-resources

In creation of UI in android projects ,why we have to refer values of string from the values folder's string.xml?

why eclipse shows warning if we assign values straight away?

I want to know the logic behind this,It's a very basic question but i couldn't find answer for this from google!

Comment: organization. for example you have string that yuoo use 10 times in app. And you want to change it later to some other due to some reason (your boss told you so for example). Other than changing it 10 times on 10 places here you change it only 1 in strings.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another reason that is not covered in the older post pointed out by KenWolf, is that now when uploading your application to the Google Play Store, you can easily make your app more accessible to other languages/locations by uploading just your strings.xml to their new translation service announced at I/O 2013. This just has to do with localizing your resources like was stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102613/android-what-is-the-main-idea-behind-of-using-strings-xml).

You can read more about it [here](http://www.androidcentral.com/new-app-translation-service-announced-google-play-developer-console).

Comment: +1, good to know about new translation service.

Answer (score 1):

There are many different advantages to using a string resource file, rather than hardcoding strings. While it may seem pointless and convoluted in small projects, it is incredibly useful in larger projects.

- If you know that you want the same string to appear in multiple places, possible occurring in separate activities, the string resource file allows you to reference one source, rather than type the string over and over again.
- If you decide to change a string in you app, or have a dynamically changing string, it is much easier to modify the resource file than it is to manually change all instances of that string in you app
- It is great for localization and translation. If someone wants to port your app to a different language, all you have to do is substitute the `strings.xml` with a translated version

Thus, it may seem useless in small applications, but for large scale applications, it makes your life much simpler and allows you to more easily reach foreign language users.

Answer (score 1):

The reason we are referring from String.xml is we can reuse the same string where ever we want.